# Printing a html template from iOS and Android

Tags: android, html, ios, css, printing

**Short: 
Is there a way to print equal looking templates from ios and android? Or is there at least a way to print html tables in WebKit with proper page breaks?**

---

**Long:**
My app needs to be able to print a list of contents. My first try was to use html to create a template and then insert the contents from code. The system works, but when the table exeeds one page, WebKit completely destroys the table. I know there are some questions on SO about page breaks in WebKit, but NONE of the solutions work.

This Image shows printing with Chrome. As you can see the page breaks nicely.

[image: Chrome]

---

This image shows the same in Safari. The page break totally destroys the table:
[image: Safari (WebKit)]

My code looks like this at the moment:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    tr {
      page-break-inside: avoid;
      page-break-before: auto;
      page-break-after: auto;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    html,
    body {
      font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
      table-layout: fixed;
      page-break-after: auto;
    }
    
    th,
    td {
      border: 0.5px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      page-break-after: auto;
    }
    
    th {
      width: 30%;
    }
    
    th+th {
      width: 40%;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    th+th+th {
      width: 15%;
    }
    
    th+th+th+th {
      width: 15%;
    }
    
    td+td {
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    td+td+td {
      text-align: right
    }
    
    h1 {
      margin-bottom: 0.2cm;
    }
    
    hr {
      background-color: #000000;
      height: 1cm;
      float: left;
    }
  </style>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsbarcode@3.11.0/dist/barcodes/JsBarcode.ean-upc.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="clear: both">
    <h1 style="float: left">Materialentnahmeliste</h1>
    <h1 style="float: right">1805/156</h1>
  </div>

  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Artikel</th>
        <th>EAN</th>
        <th>Menge</th>
        <th>Verbr.</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <script>
      const barcodes = [5413184160722, 4012615997145, 4004631016214, 5413184160593, 5413184160616, 5413184160654, 5413184160692, 4004631009315, 4004631047096, 4004631010977, 4210201175469, 5413184151492, 4004631062198, 4004631009476, 4004631011660, 4002515500361, 4012615996636, 4242002957005, 5413184104139, 5413184104047, 5413184170301, 4004631006567, 4002515824481, 4002515824528, 4002515942420, 5413184160968, 4004631000749, 4016803170921, 4016803174820, 4016803178187, 3121040039830, 5413184160081, 4002515932773, 4016803171263, 4016803037330, 4002515824177, 5413184122935, 4001797672001].map(String)

      barcodes.forEach(barcode => {
        document.write(`
                        <tr>
                            <td>${barcode}</td>
                            <td><svg id="b${barcode}"></svg></td>
                            <td>10000m</td>
                            <td>tet</td>
                        </tr>
                    `)
      })
    </script>
  </table>

  <p style="text-align:left;">
    Ausgegeben von:
    <span style="float:right;">Nov 25, 2018 at 3:00 PM</span>
  </p>
  <hr style="border: none">

  <script>
    barcodes.forEach(barcode => {
      JsBarcode("#b" + barcode, barcode, {
        format: "EAN13",
        height: 25,
        width: 2,
        flat: true,
        displayValue: true,
        margin: 2
      });
    })
  </script>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: For iOS you can user `JavaScriptCore` framework to load `HTML` code and generate pdf. Which can be load into WebView. You can also iterate dynamic data into html using javascript and for ios `JSContext` class be help for it to bind data.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show the image from your android app , first you need to save this html on android internal storage, then using webview you can show the data as per given above image.

```
 mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/new.html");
 mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

[image]